# Google App Engine Eclipse plugin - all the console output in red

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, logging

I've just tried the first Google App Engine Java tutorial using Eclipse Indigo with Google Plugin on Windows. Everything seems to work but I'm wondering about the javaw.exe console output which is shown all in red, INFO's included (can't post images):

```
2012-06-04 23:50:42 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
2012-06-04 23:50:42 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

Is it supposed to work that way? Is it just because javaw.exe spits all of these out on its stderr and there's no filtering on the Eclipse side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, red output in the console from the Google Plugin for Eclipse is perfectly normal. I'm not sure if there is a technical reason for it being red, or if it was a conscious style choice, but it's like that on every installation of Eclipse + GPE that I've ever used.